# Fed ex integration in my localhost eCommerce store

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, fedex

I got all my credentials my Developer Test Key,Test Account Number, Test Meter Number,Test Password and Test url.

when I am trying to enter my 9 digit account number(i got in my email) and nickname and it is giving me an error of "Account number is invalid."

and i want to know what to do with test url and how to use all these credentials in my eCommerce store.

Please do help me out with step by step process of fedex integration in my local host website.

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It doesn't work this way.  You can't dump a screen shot from your app and half a database description and expect to get meaningful help.  Please updatr your question and let us know what your specific programming question is.

Comment: Follow a lead here: http://abhijeetkarmakar.com/getting-fedex-test-credentials-magento/